# Kato's inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let u be a smooth function defined in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. The well known Kato's inequality states
$$|∇|∇u||^2≤|∇^2u|^2$$
where $∇^2$ represents the Hessian operator of $M$.
I would like ask if someone can shows me a short proof for this inequality or giving me a reference within I can find the proof.
Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 16):

Where $\nabla u \ne 0,$ this is simple calculus: The product rule tells us

$$\nabla |\nabla u| = \frac{\nabla (g(\nabla u,\nabla u))}{2 |\nabla u|}=\frac{g(\nabla^2u,\nabla u)}{|\nabla u|}.$$

Taking the squared norm and estimating the numerator with Cauchy-Schwarz gives us $$|\nabla|\nabla u||^2 \le \frac{|\nabla^2 u|^2 |\nabla u|^2}{|\nabla u|^2} = |\nabla^2 u|^2$$ as desired.

In general, we have to interpret things weakly: for an arbitrary smooth function $u,$  $|\nabla u|$ is only Lipschitz, so we must interpret $\nabla |\nabla u|$ as a weak/distributional derivative. Thankfully, we at least know (thanks to Rademacher) that this distribution is in fact in $L^\infty_\rm{loc};$ so both sides of the proposed distributional inequality $$|\nabla|\nabla u||^2\le |\nabla^2u|^2$$ are in $L^\infty_\rm{loc}$ and thus it suffices to prove the inequality almost everywhere.

At points where $\nabla u \ne 0,$ the calculation I did at the start of my answer suffices.

At a point where $|\nabla u| = 0$ and $|\nabla u|$ is classically differentiable, we know $|\nabla u|$ is at a local minimum and thus $\nabla |\nabla u| = 0,$ so the inequality holds since the RHS is manifestly non-negative.

The set of points where $\nabla u=0$ and $|\nabla u|$ is not classically differentiable has measure zero, so we're done.

Comment: I am confused about the second equality in the first equation, in $g(\nabla^2 u,\nabla u)$ is it the inner product of covariant 2 tensor and vector field?

Comment: @H-H: it's the (metric) contraction of a 2-tensor and a 1-tensor, resulting in a 1-tensor. (For me these tensors are all covariant, but you can of course turn them into vector fields using the metric.) In index notation, $\theta = g(\nabla^2 u,\nabla u)$ is simply $\theta_i = g^{kl}(\nabla^2u)_{ki}(\nabla u)_l.$

Comment: What about the zero-set of $\nabla u$?

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyCarapetis. Hmm. Okay, $|\nabla^2 u|(p_i) \to |\nabla^2 u|(p)$ because $u$ is of class $C^2$. But why does $|\nabla |\nabla u||(p_i)$ converge to $|\nabla |\nabla u||(p)$ even if the latter exists? If $\nabla u(p) = 0$ then $\nabla |\nabla u|$ is probably discontinuous at $p$...

Comment: Looks like I was a bit late deleting my reply! Indeed, $\nabla|\nabla u|$ might not even exist in the classical sense (consider the simple example $u=|x|^2$ ). I think you need to interpret Kato's inequality in the sense of distributions for it to be true in general.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Well yeah, the proof is actually not as easy as people tend to think... Btw., by Rademachers theorem, $\nabla | \nabla u|$ exists almost everywhere because $| \cdot |$ and $\nabla u$ are Lipschitz-continuous. But still one has to analyze the set of points $x$ where $\nabla | \nabla u|(x)$ exists although $\nabla u (x) =0$... Is this set a nullset? And if yes, why?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: it's not a null set, but it's very easy to analyze: see my edit.

Comment: Ah, very nice and simple. Have my upvote.

Comment: Actually, you don't use distributions here at all. The derivative in Rademacher's theorem is the classical (total) derivative.

Comment: Well, I guess I like to be overly careful with this stuff: the fact that a function is classically differentiable almost everywhere does not imply that this a.e. derivative is its distributional derivative (e.g. in the case of a step functino), and it's usually the distributional derivative that we actually care about. Here, the full version of Rademacher (including the result $C^{0,1}=W^{1,\infty}$) tells us that the distributional and a.e. derivatives are one and the same; so after this point we don't have to worry about it.