# How to use Kato's inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

I am studying this book: Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds (Emmanuel Hebey). We have Kato's inequality
$$
|\nabla|\nabla^su||\leq |\nabla^{s+1}u|,\mbox{ a.e. },\forall u\in C^\infty(M),
$$
and we want to proof:

**Theorem 2.7:** Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth, compact Riemannian $n$-manifold, $q\geq1$ real, and  $m<k$ two integers. If $\frac1q<\frac{k-m}{n}$, then $H^q_k(M)\subset C^m(M)$.

In the proof, Hebey use Kato's inequality to conclude: for every $u\in C^\infty(M)$, there exist $C>0$ such that
$$
\|\nabla^su\|_{H^q_{k-s}}\leq C\|u\|_{H_k^q},
$$
where $s\in\{0,\ldots,m\}$. I do not understand how to use Kato's inequality.

**My try:** I claim that $|\nabla^i|\nabla^su||\leq|\nabla^{i+s}u|$ a.e.. If this inequality it is true, we get
$$
\|\nabla^su\|_{H^q_{k-s}}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-s}\||\nabla^i|\nabla^su||\|_{L^q}\leq\sum_{i=0}^{k-s}\||\nabla^{i+s}u|\|_{L^q}\leq\|u\|_{H^q_k}.
$$
I tried proof $|\nabla^i|\nabla^su||\leq|\nabla^{i+s}u|$ by induction but I could not.

Comment: You will drastically increase your chances of getting an answer by making your question self-contained. What is $H_k^q$? What is $\nabla^s$?

Comment: $\nabla^su$ is the $s^{th}$ covariant derivate of $u$. The Sobolev space $H^q_k(M)$ is the completion of $\mathcal  C^q_k(M)$, where $\mathcal C^q_k(M)=\{u\in C^\infty(M)/\forall j=0,\ldots,k,\int_M|\nabla^ju|^qdv(g)<\infty\}$ with the norm $\|u\|_{H_k^p}=\sum_{j=0}^k\|\nabla^ju\|_{L^q}$.

Comment: Does Katos inequality hold pointwise or is an integral implicit in the outer norms? Further even if $u\in C^\infty(M)$ you may have that $|\nabla^{s}u|$ is not differentiable. Although it will likely be weakly differentiable it will not be weakly twice differentiable, giving a problem when you want to look at $\nabla^i|\nabla^s u|$. What concrete meaning is given to $\nabla |\nabla^su|$?

Comment: If you do not know Kato's inequality, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766633/katos-inequality (in this question $s=1$, but it is not difficult generalize for all $s$). Basically, since $|\nabla^su|$ is locally Lipschitz, we have that $|\nabla^su|\in H_k^q(\Omega)$ for all $\Omega$ such that $\overline\Omega\subset M$ is compact and $q\in[1,\infty)$.